# I have a css fail I need fix

Tags: html, css

Why doesn't this code work on my computer? I expected my welcome to be displayed with an Arial font.

```
<h1 style="font-family: arial;"></h1>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
```

Comment: Please define "does not work". What does not work? What do you expect?

Comment: What doesn't work - what do you expect to happen? What doesn't happen?

Comment: Style, defined directly in teg, affects only this teg, and, depending of style, tags children.

Comment: My code wasn't working the code on stackoverflow and I was showing it to you guys to see if you knew why.

Comment: Okay of course it is unclear what he is asking but it looks like he is 10 years old or so.. don't be so harsh and give him 9 downvotes, come on, I think it is good to start with programming and develope such interest in that age

Comment: Thank you Ibrahim Apachi I am around that age.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only CSS there is applied to an `h1` that has no text. Since it has no text, you cannot see the change in font.

You need to either move the style attribute to the element with text:

```
<h1 style="font-family: arial;">Welcome</h1>
```

Or use a proper stylesheet.

```
    <style>
        h1 {
            font-family: arial;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
```

(External style sheets associated with an HTML document via a `<link>` element are preferred.

Comment: +1 As I think this is what the OP wants. Well explained too.

Answer (score 2):

When you style an element using attributes in the opening tab it's just applied to that element so you could use `<h1 style="font-family: arial;">Welcome</h1>` this instead. but if you want to apply a style to all h1 elements you should write the style either in the head element like this:

```
<head>
<style>
h1{
font-family: arial;
}
</style>
</head>
```

or in a separate CSS file.

Comment: This isn't how CSS works.

Comment: `head` element cannot contain `body`; it can contain `style`, though. Ensure you are spreading correct knowledge before posting an answer.

Comment: I've changed this error

Answer (score 1):

Use this - it will be understand easily 
save this file in home.html and run in any browser.

```
<body>
<h1 style="font-family: arial;">Welcome</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<h1 style="font-family: arial;">Welcome</h1>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

your  css :

```
h1 {
  font-family: arial;
}
```

and your html :

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
```

you must assign your style at the right tag. In your code you have two h1 tags. If you apply a style tag directly in the first, the second will not be impacted. If you are working with a stylesheet as in my example, both will be impacted because I directly reference the style for all balsies h1.